# Spinner with Select One throws IndexOutOfBoundsException?

Tags: android, android-spinner

I'm trying insert in my BaseAdapter of a Spinner the text: "Select one option". The problem is after insert this text my spinner stop works and throws an exception `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

How could I solve it ?

**Spinner**

```
Spinner spin = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.mySpinner);
ConsultaClienteVendaProdutoListAdapter adapter = new ConsultaClienteVendaProdutoListAdapter(this, lista);
spin.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**BaseAdapter**

```
public class ConsultaClienteVendaProdutoListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
private List<Cliente> list;
private Context context;


public ConsultaClienteVendaProdutoListAdapter(List<Cliente> list, Context context) {
    this.list = list;
    this.context = context;
}

public void changeList(List<Cliente> list){
    this.list = list;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    Cliente cli = null;
    list.add(0, cli);

    if (convertView == null) {

        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.consulta_cliente_venda_produto_adapter, parent, false);

        viewHolder.llClienteAdapter = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.llClienteAdapter);
        viewHolder.tvNome = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvNome);


        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }else{
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }

    Cliente cliente = list.get(position -1);

    if(position == 0){
        viewHolder.tvNome.setText("Select one option");
    }else{
        viewHolder.tvNome.setText(cliente.getNome());
    }

    return convertView;
}


/** pattern view holder */
private static class ViewHolder{
    LinearLayout llClienteAdapter;
    TextView tvNome;
}
```

}

**Exception**

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 2, size is 2
            at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
            at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
            at br.com.williarts.kontrole.listadap.ConsultaClienteVendaProdutoListAdapter.getView(ConsultaClienteVendaProdutoListAdapter.java:53)
            at android.widget.BaseAdapter.getDropDownView(BaseAdapter.java:71)
            at android.widget.Spinner$DropDownAdapter.getDropDownView(Spinner.java:886)
            at android.widget.Spinner$DropDownAdapter.getView(Spinner.java:882)
            at android.widget.Spinner.measureContentWidth(Spinner.java:762)
            at android.widget.Spinner$DropdownPopup.computeContentWidth(Spinner.java:1123)
            at android.widget.Spinner$DropdownPopup.show(Spinner.java:1149)
            at android.widget.Spinner.performClick(Spinner.java:675)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19330)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: At the top of your `getView` method, you have 2 calls to `list.get()` , you prob. only need the one in the `if` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It because on the method getCount() you should have list.size() only. Because you have list.size() +1 it makes the adapter believe it has one more element. And when it requests this it doesn't exist.

@Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size() +1;
    }

The error most likely occurs at line Cliente cliente = list.get(position).

If you want to add the string "Select one option" in the spinner you could just add it in the list that you are using as your data source or replace Cliente cliente = list.get(position) with just Cliente cliente=null;

Comment: you say to create an object `Cliente cliente = null` after add this cliente null into list `list.add(0, cliente);` that's it ? I'm trying do it works but I can't. How could I do it work ?

Comment: The way lists work is that if your list has 3 elements you can at most request the element at position 2 because lists are indexed from 0. That means that in relation to a mathematical list the first element belongs to position 0, the second to position 1 and so on. What you are trying to do is get an item at a certain position which would work fine if you didn't have  return list.size() +1 in get count. In your case you are tricking the adapter into believing it has 3 elements when it has 2. So for this to be successful you also have to modify getView method accordingly

Comment: Firstly I would put if(position==0) condition and do whatever you wanna do for the "Select one option case" and then have an else method where you manipulate every other case but bear in mind that wherever you would normally use position as an index now you have to use position - 1

Comment: @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;      
        if (convertView == null) {
           //exactly as before in here
        }
  else{
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }

        if (position == 0) {
            viewHolder.tvNome.setText("Select one option");
        } else {
  Cliente cliente = list.get(position-1);
            viewHolder.tvNome.setText(cliente.getNome());
        }
        return convertView;
    }

Comment: Could you edit your post with an example ? I'm trying, but still cant do it works.

Comment: I did. My previous comment is exactly that. just not very nicely formatted as a comment :) If you copy and paste it it should work

Comment: You shouldn't be adding any more elements to your list as this is already populated. If you copy and paste my code in the comment that begins with @Override and just paste it it should be enough and then replace the "//exactly as before in here" comment with  what ever was between the braces before

Comment: your suggestion works, but only one result is shown. My list has 2 objects Cliente but only one object is showing.

Comment: That would be because you have now changed @Override
public int getCount() {
    return list.size();
} instead of return list.size()+1; You can have one or the other

Answer (score 1):

Your `getSize()` return `list.size() +1`, so `getView()` is called for all number between 0 and `list.size() +1` - 1.

And the second line of `getView()` make a get on `list`.
If your `list` has 1 element,

- `getSize()` return 2
- `getView()` make a `Cliente cliente = list.get(1);`

it doesn't exist in the list! (only `[...].get(0)` exist).

You have to change to:

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list.size();
}
```

and change in `getView()`:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    Cliente cliente = list.get(position);
    if (convertView == null) {
[...]
```